# How to find a symbol address on startup?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++11, visual-studio-2013

By adding the following to the registry, I can get the debugger to attach to a process when it executes:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Image File Execution Options\<executable>.exe]
"debugger"="vsjitdebugger.exe"
```

However, I'd like to get the address of a static variable, but as it is not within scope or even loaded as it is in a dll that is delayed loaded, how can I:

1. Stop the debugger when it loads the dll
2. Get the address of a variable that is at file scope

The application is written in C++.

Comment: Do you have access to the source code and PDBs?

Comment: @Cameron, Yes, it is all available to me.

Comment: Then you can place a breakpoint in DllMain :-)

Comment: @Cameron, there are many dlls being loaded.  How do I stop when the particular dll I want is loading?  And when it does, how do I find the symbol I'm looking for?

Comment: @Cameron, are you talking about the `DllMain()` that is located in the `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\atlmfc\src\mfc\dllinit.cpp` file?

Comment: @Arian: I mean, place a breakpoint in the `DllMain` function of the DLL you care about. Windows invokes that function when the DLL is first attached to the process. If there isn't one, you can add a dummy one (provided you can modify the source code -- otherwise you'll need to find another way, this is just the simplest that came to my mind).